# How to send bulk sms using usb modem in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, sms

I have successfully coded to send sms to one mobile number at a time, but I want to send it as bulk.

I am using a textbox to feed number I want to input several numbers to the textbox and send to all numbers in that text box.

Here is the form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;
using GsmComm.PduConverter.SmartMessaging;
using GsmComm.GsmCommunication;
using GsmComm.Interfaces;
using GsmComm.Server;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace yahapalana_DB
{
    public partial class sms : Form
    {
        public sms()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private GsmCommMain comm;
        private delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        private SmsServer smsServer;

        TextBox txtmsg = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtno = new TextBox();


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalied Port Name");
                return;
            }
            comm = new GsmCommMain(comboBox1.Text, 9600, 150);
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            bool retry;
            do
            {
                retry = false;
                try
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    comm.Open();
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    MessageBox.Show("Connect Successfully");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Modem not available", "Check", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Retry) retry = true;
                    { return; }
                }
            } while (retry);
        }

        private void sms_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Com1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Com2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Com3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Com4");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {

                string[] slist = text.Split(':');
                SmsSubmitPdu pdu;
                byte dcs = (byte)DataCodingScheme.GeneralCoding.Alpha7BitDefault;
                pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(textmsg.Text,mobno.Text,dcs);
                int times = 1;
                for (int i=0;i<times;i++) {
                    comm.SendMessage(pdu);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Message sent sucessfully");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Modem not avaliable");
            }  
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            add_number au = new add_number();
            au.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, you are splitting your string from the textbox but you never use it. I have extended your for by a foreach and replaced mobno.Text by the item from the numbers item.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {

            string[] slist = text.Split(':');

            foreach (string mobno in slist) {
                SmsSubmitPdu pdu;
                byte dcs = (byte)DataCodingScheme.GeneralCoding.Alpha7BitDefault;
                pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(textmsg.Text,mobno,dcs);
                int times = 1;

                comm.SendMessage(pdu);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Message sent sucessfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Modem not avaliable");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok. And what did you tried? What is the error message? Did you tried to debug if everywhere the expected valued etc. ?

Comment: I have a concept like this: I will load few numbers from mysql database and select numbers from that and load numbers to mobno textbox and using array format numbers in the textbox and store numbers in the array and using send button send it to all the numbers which are on the array. I want to know actually how to do that! thanks for help appriciate it mate!!!

Comment: And the above will to that. Did you debug the code above? What is the error? What have you tried? Why arent you looping directly through the database result and sending the sms out?